# Hide, show div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I do FAQ page in my site. And have some problem with hide/show div blocks with answer to questions. I need to hide block if second time clicked on same link or other link.
[jsfiddle link with code here](http://jsfiddle.net/p2622b1t/)

```
 <div  class="question">
<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes1');" >First question?</a></div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: block;" > </div>
 <div  class="question">
<a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes2');" >Second question?</a>   </div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: none;" > </div>
```

JS:

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).slideDown(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }
     });
}
```

How to close div block if user second clicked on same block?
I tried with  help markers, but it not work.

Comment: With minimal code changes: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2622b1t/2/).

Comment: And [version](http://jsfiddle.net/p2622b1t/7/) without outdated inline JS and overcomplicated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').each(function (index) {
        $(this).slideUp(600);
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone && !$(this).is(':visible')) {
            $(this).slideDown(200);
        }
    });
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/p2622b1t/3/)

Alternatively, you don't need to use loop try it like,

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').slideUp(600);
    var $id=$('#'+thechosenone);
    if ( !$id.is(':visible')) {
        $id.slideDown(200);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/p2622b1t/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `.slideToggle()` the content when id is matched(i.e. inside if condition) . However you can simply optimize the code to:

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $('.newboxes').not('#'+thechosenone).slideUp(600);
  $('.newboxes#'+thechosenone).slideToggle(200);
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d576bwy7/)**

Comment: toggle up speed equal toggle down speed, it does not suit me

Comment: @T_E_M_A: how hard is it to chage the slideUp parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Please use slideToggle instead of slideDown. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/m9bdLw4c/1/

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).slideToggle(200);

      }
      else {
           $(this).slideUp(600);

      }

 });
```

(Edit: Sorry, already been answered whilst I was editing. Didn't mean to duplicate!)

Answer (score 1):

Set an active css class for opened element. So you can decide which element is openend and has to be closed on second click. Here the code:

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
          if( $(this).hasClass( 'active' )) {
               $(this).slideUp(600).removeClass( 'active' );
          } else {
              $(this).slideDown(200).addClass( 'active' );
          }               
      }
      else {
           $(this).slideUp(600);
      }
 });
}
```

A demo you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/p2622b1t/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this..

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
              if($(this).hasClass("open"))
              {
                  $(this).slideUp(600);
                  $(this).removeClass("open");
              }
              else
              {
               $(this).slideDown(200);
              $(this).addClass("open");
              }
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }
     });
}
```